# Jenkins how to trigger build on a schedule only when there are changes

Tags: git, jenkins, incremental-build

In our Jenkins and git setup, the master is Windows and the slaves are Linux. (sometime in the next few months that will be changed to linux all).

when you set Poll SCM in a job, the poll action takes place at the master, not the slave where the job is configured to run. Anyhow.. there is a problem with the server config, and I cannot run git there AND reach the repo on another machine thru SSH.

net, I cannot use poll scm until the server is fixed.

however, I have a build job that needs to run whenever there are changes, as it builds the artifacts used to auto deploy the application for further testing. 
I can use Build Regularly, but it will build every 30 mins (just as an example), and nightly and over the weekend and most of the time this is a waste of time.

so, I want to create some timed job, that checks something to see if there are changes since the last time.  the Build happens only for content in a specific branch.

I 'think' I can use rev-list to get the last commit, but I only want the commit in the particular branch.   then I could save this to a file and recheck on the next of this side job.

if the revisions don't match, then trigger the other job.

anyone have any better guidance?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are mistaken. The SCM poll happens on one of the slaves where the job is configured to run. At least this is the way it works with jobs configured to use git. If your polls run on the Windows master, it is because you have not checked the box "Restrict where this job can run" in the job configuration, and specified a group of nodes that excludes the master.

Comment: I do so wish you were correct.. but it is absolutely confirmed that the poll happens on the master in our case.

Comment: the job is configured to run ONLY on the slave node running linux. I can use the windows task manager to see the git.exe process hung waiting for the ssh password prompt, which will never come, and eventually the connection times out (about 10 minutes).. the first error was the we configured only for the unix git executable (/usr/bin/git, not c:/git_windows/git), and it couldn't find the file (/usr/bin/git). then we took the path off, and it couldn't find 'git'.

Comment: Strange. Is it a free-style job or a multi-configuration job or something else? Is there cloned workspace in the master? Maybe it helps to remove it to force Jenkins to clone in one of the linux slaves and hopefully run the polls where the workspace is.

Comment: Its a maven job. The repo is cloned onto the slave, not the master.

the master did not have git installed before enabling SCM Polling on this job. (so could not have clone to the master)

this is the only git related job on this jenkins installation. ( a hundred jobs and 20 slaves)

this slave is dedicated to this git based repo

Comment: I will add that the master is configured 'use this slave as much as possible' in the Manage Jenkins page, Usage setting. As I am not the system admin, I do not want to change it.